# tensorflow assign values of 2D tensor by indices when 1st dimension of the tensor is unknown [in keras.layers.Layer]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am implementing a keras layer, and its `call` function needs to achieve 2D Tensor value assign by indices. The function is demonstrated by python numpy as follows:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.arange(12).reshape(6,2)
ind_x = [2,4,5]
ind_y = [0,1,0]
A[(ind_x,ind_y)] = -1 # assign value 
A = array([[ 0,  1],
           [ 2,  3],
           [-1,  5],
           [ 6,  7],
           [ 8, -1],
           [-1, 11]])
```

If `A.shape = (6,2)` is available, then `tf.SparseTensor` is perfect for this purpose.

However in my case, A is the input of keras.layers.Layer, thus its first dimension (i.e. batch size) is undetermined during graph construction. In the end, `A.shape = (None,2)`. Is there any other tensorflow function can achieve this? Thanks.

P.S. A question was asked with full keras implementation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640036/keras-with-tensorflow-backend-layer-implementation-when-batch-size-is-used-but). However, I think the question might be clearer and more fundamental here.

Comment: The indices in the example are `(2,0) , (4,1)  (5,0)` ?

Comment: Yes, they are. In my case, ind_x and ind_y are calculated from two tensors, so both of them are vectors.

Comment: A similar question was asked with full keras implementation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52640036/keras-with-tensorflow-backend-layer-implementation-when-batch-size-is-used-but